# Jquery Modal not closing correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplemodal

I'm having a problem with my jquery modal its not closing correctly in internet explorer but works fine in chrome.

JS is not my strong subject so cant work it out. Here the code I'm using to open the modal and the close script

```
    jQuery(function ($) {
    var login = {
        message: null,
        init: function () {
            $('#login').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                // load the contact form using ajax
                $.get("../_Includes/login.php", function(data){
                    // create a modal dialog with the data
                    $(data).modal({
                        closeHTML: "<a href='#' title='Close' class='modal-close'>x</a>",
                        position: ["15%",],
                        overlayId: 'login-overlay',
                        containerId: 'login-container',
                        onOpen: login.open,
                        onShow: login.show,
                        onClose: login.close
                    });
                });
            });
        },
        open: function (dialog) {       
            dialog.overlay.fadeIn(200, function () {
                dialog.container.fadeIn(200, function () {
                    dialog.data.fadeIn(200, function () {
                        $('#login-container').animate({
                            height: h
                        }, function () {
                            $('#login-container form').fadeIn(200, function () {
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        },
        show: function (dialog) {
        $('#loginForm').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();$('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        var url = "../_Scripts/login.php";
        if (!username) {
            $('input[type=submit]', this).removeAttr('disabled');
            $("#loginReply").html('<img src="../_Images/round_error.png" alt="Error" width="31" height="30" /> &nbsp; Please enter your Username.').show().fadeOut(6000);
            return false;
        }
        else if (!password) {
            $('input[type=submit]', this).removeAttr('disabled');
            $("#loginReply").html('<img src="../_Images/round_error.png" alt="Error" width="31" height="30" /> &nbsp; Please enter your Password.').show().fadeOut(6000); 
            return false;
        }  
        else {
            $('input[type=submit]', this).removeAttr('disabled');
            $.post(url, $('#loginForm').serialize(), function (data) {
                if(data.status == true){ 
                    window.location = data.action;
                 } else{
                    $("#loginReply").html(data.action).show().fadeOut(10000);
                    $("#username").val('');
                    $("#password").val(''); 
                    $("#loginProcessGif").hide();
                    }
            });
        }
        }); 
        },
        close: function (dialog) {
                dialog.overlay.fadeOut(200, function () {
                    $.modal.close();
                });         
        },
    };
    login.init();
});
```

Can anyone shed some light on this????

Thanks

Comment: what is the error you getting ? update your requirements clearly

Comment: I get no errors it just wont close

Comment: no errors then what is the problem. please update it in fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/V9ewh/

Comment: nope nothing in console. also cant seem to get the fiddle working